# How PDO prepared statements help to prevent SQL vulnerable statements?

Tags: sql, pdo

I'm so confused or rather I'm like, soooooooooo confused with pdo prepared statements. I know that prepared statements are the best way to keep data safe from hackers.

From : [How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)

> We are sending program to the server first
>
> $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id=?"); where the data is
>   substituted by some variable called "placeholder".
>
> Note that the very same query being sent to the server, without any
>   data in it! And then we're sending the data with the second request,
>   totally separated from the query itself:
>
> $db->execute($data);

query-

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username=?");
$query->execute(array($tex));
$tex=blah; DROP TABLE users;--
```

then it will be like - SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username=blah; DROP TABLE users;--

how prepare statements will help me with this example above?

I'm really sorry if this question is vague to understand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The prepared statement handler will make sure the bound value is *always used as valid SQL value/literal* (ie. an SQL string or a number) and *never* as 'raw SQL text'<sup>1</sup>.

This is why placeholders values *cannot* be used as identifiers such as column or table names or act as other SQL keywords; and *cannot* generate the vulnerable query hypothesized. Instead it is treated as the following:

```sql
WHERE username='blah; DROP TABLE users;--'
            --^ placeholder ensures valid SQL string value is used
            --  (note automatic/implicit addition of SQL quotes)
```

And even when binding with 'more tricky' data:

```php
$tex = "blah'; DROP TABLE users;--";  // embedded SQL quote character
```

It would still be safe:

```sql
WHERE username='blah''; DROP TABLE users;--'
            --^ placeholder STILL ensures valid SQL string value is used
```

Thus, when using placeholders, it is *impossible* to generate the SQL that is vulnerable (in this way).

For [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) the 'shape' of the query (which includes keywords and identifiers, but *excludes* values) must itself be altered by the input.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically placeholders values can also be sent through a *separate* data channel (depending on adapter/driver) and thus might not even appear in the raw SQL query itself.

However a simple way to think about why placeholders are safe, or how they 'work' is:

When using placeholders the adapter ensures that the equivalent of 'sql really safe escape' and applicable quoting is *always* used for every bound text value - and is thus impossible for accidentally forget.

Comment: you are saying that while using placeholders it is impossible to generate sql that is vulnerable. but what i want to know is how placeholders do that thing? I mean - htmlspecialchars() function converts some predefined characters(&,",',<,>) to HTML entities, addslashes() function  returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters. like these functions how placeholders detect that the value is not in the proper format or the value is not good for querying?

Comment: **Stop**. It does no such thing. Placeholders ensure the values *are supplied as valid SQL values*. It has *nothing* to do with HTML or entities or slashes. Placeholders *only* ensure that the data is transferred correctly *without* chance of SQL Injection. *Placeholders never alter the actual value.* In the above examples I've shown how this could be represented in SQL queries with proper (ANSI) SQL syntax.

Comment: (Assuming that the placeholders build the actual SQL query the "method" would be with `mysqli_real_escape_string` or equivalent.)